# finding relative co-ordinates of android device using location services with accuracy in cm

Tags: android, geolocation

I have tried using location services like **GPS** and network provider.
I am getting accuracy of 16 m. i need in cm or at least 1 meter.
Could any tell me any other method for better estimate.
Basically i want to find relative co-ordinates of the device with respect a location which is found by that device only.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  GPS isn't that accurate, not without very specialized equipment.  http://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/    GPS was designed to get 8 meter accuracy with 95% confidence, and good equipment can get 3 meter accuracy.  Military grade equipment can probably do even better, but you won't even get the good stuff in a mobile phone, forget military.

ANd that's assuming the military isn't purposely messing with the signal-  the US military can purposely make it less accurate in times of war.